# Setting browser language as the default for Angular 5 site

Tags: angular

We are using Angular 5.1.1 and trying to add multiple languages to our site so visitors can select their desired language and/or we can default to the language configured by their browser. We have gone through all the Internationalization (i18n) guidance on the Angular.io site and it all seems to suggest you can only have one alternate language and there is no guidance on how to detect the browsers configured language or even toggle between a single and target language.

Can someone shed some light on if/how we can have multiple languages and how we can change the default language presented based on the browsers configured language?

Here is how we are loading the XLIFF files but we don't know how to toggle between them within the active session

```
const translations = [
    require(`raw-loader!./app/locale/messages.en.xlf`),
    require(`raw-loader!./app/locale/messages.fr.xlf`),
    require(`raw-loader!./app/locale/messages.pt.xlf`),
];

const providers = [
    { provide: INITIAL_CONFIG, useValue: { document: '<app></app>', url: params.url } },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
    { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations },
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' }
];
```

The guidance tells us to set **LOCAL_ID** but this appears to just hard code one language

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl },
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw a really good solution to load the language dynamically based on the browser. Basically you just have to create a new provider for the translation and within that provider do the following:

```
let locale = query the default language of the browser here and store it!

const file = `/path/to/translations/site.${locale}.xlf`;
```

and finally pass it back as a Promise:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('GET', file);
  xhr.onload = (data: any) => resolve(
    [
      { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: data.target.response },
      { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
      { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: locale }
    ]
  );
  xhr.onerror = () => reject(noProviders);
  xhr.send();
});
```

Comment: How to you get the browser language using TypeScript?

Comment: navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage that should work!

Comment: when I add that I get `NodeInvocationException: navigator is not defined`

Comment: what about window.navigator?

Comment: I get `NodeInvocationException: window is not defined`. Your response is appreciated but I just can't make this work from the fragment you supplied.

Comment: Must be a problem on your side, check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-8y6wow

Comment: We are using 5.1.1 and not 5.0.0 so maybe that is this issue, we also do not have the beta dependencies in your project so we will have to figure out what these are before adding.

Comment: @Embrioka navigator saved my life in 2021. Thank you!